# SWIFT: Failed with exit code 1 (WHY?)

Tags: swift, compiler-errors

My App has been compiling happily for months and then all of a sudden I get the dreaded "Failed with exit code 1". I am not aware that I changed anything. CMD-SHIFT-Ks etc don't seem to have helped. Any ideas?

Error messages read:(does this help?)

```
CopySwiftLibs /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app (in target: Solar123)
    cd /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk
    builtin-swiftStdLibTool --copy --verbose --sign 3C33BF10C9109D7712B3EDFF83ED8164121F3378 --scan-executable /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Solar123 --scan-folder /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks --scan-folder /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/PlugIns --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework --platform iphoneos --toolchain /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain --destination /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks --strip-bitcode --resource-destination /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app --resource-library libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib --strip-bitcode-tool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip --emit-dependency-info /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Solar123.build/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.build/SwiftStdLibToolInputDependencies.dep

Requested Swift ABI version based on scanned binaries: unstable(7)
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCore.dylib to /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCore.dylib -r -o /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib to /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib -r -o /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftos.dylib to /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftos.dylib -r -o /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib to /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib -r -o /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreImage.dylib to /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreImage.dylib -r -o /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftUIKit.dylib to /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftUIKit.dylib -r -o /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftFoundation.dylib to /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftFoundation.dylib -r -o /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib to /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib -r -o /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib to /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib -r -o /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftDispatch.dylib to /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftDispatch.dylib -r -o /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib to /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib -r -o /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftDarwin.dylib to /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftDarwin.dylib -r -o /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib to /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib -r -o /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftMetal.dylib to /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftMetal.dylib -r -o /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftMapKit.dylib to /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftMapKit.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftMapKit.dylib -r -o /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftMapKit.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib to /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib
Probing signature of /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign -r- --display /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
/Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: code object is not signed at all

Codesigning /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 3C33BF10C9109D7712B3EDFF83ED8164121F3378 --verbose /Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
/Users/edward/Desktop/Solar123/DerivedData/Solar123/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Solar123.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: errSecInternalComponent

error: Failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Think it's a bit more complex than that (just been on the phone to Apple for the last three hours). Am on Catalina (10.15) and the KeyChain password is not working. Dragged the KeyChain folder onto the desktop and restarted, repopulated the KeyChain and issue persists. Created new Admin user and still won't accept the KeyChain password. Any ideas?

Comment: This is a KeyChain issue. Just had an update from Apple and the problem has disappeared whilst resetting the entire KeyChain. When I get more details from them I'll post them up. Many thanks to all.